# Unit-independent position_nudge

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to apply a position_nudge to an object, but it should always be a certain distance (e.g. in "cm") rather than relative to the scale of the measured variable.

```
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("de","gb","cn","ir","ru") ,
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45)*1
)

ggplot(data, 
       aes(x=name, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0,
                label = paste0(name,value)),
            position = position_nudge(y = -12)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 50), # This focuses the x-axis on the range of interest
                  clip = 'off') +   # This keeps the labels from disappearing
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "lines"))
```

[image]

When changing the scale of the variable, that adjustment should not need to be made in the position_nudge argument, e.g.

```
factor = 100
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("de","gb","cn","ir","ru") ,
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45)*factor
)

ggplot(data, 
       aes(x=name, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0,
                label = paste0(name,value)),
            position = position_nudge(y = -12)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 50*factor), # This focuses the x-axis on the range of interest
                  clip = 'off') +   # This keeps the labels from disappearing
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "lines"))
```

Currently, this does not work, so that I need to manually change -12 to -1200 to achieve this:

[image]

This is of course only a short reproducible example, the actual use-case is placing country flags as x-axis labels below the plot.

The final product will look somewhat like this, but currently requires updating the nudges each time the y-values change:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you considered just multiplying nudge with the same factor? Using fixed distances is a bit tricky in ggplot and I am not so sure if this is really what you want

Comment: Have also been thinking about that. Maybe multiply nudge based on the maximum bar/ylim. Because the nudge will have to change proportionally...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest "hack" is to make this two plots and bind them with patchwork or cowplot. If you try it differently, you'd soon get into deep grid ... trouble.

**Related**

[baptiste on github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1244)

[baptiste on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997715/add-ggplot-annotation-outside-the-panel-or-two-titles)

[Sandy Muspratt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51814637/7941188)

**The easy way**:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

foo <- data.frame(
  name=c("de","gb","cn","ir","ru") ,
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45)*1
)
foo_label = paste(foo$name, foo$value)

p <- ggplot(foo, aes(x=name, y=value)) +
  geom_blank() # essential, so that both plots have same scaling

p_1 <- 
  p + geom_col() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 50),clip = 'off') +  
  theme(plot.margin = margin()) 

p_text <- 
  p + annotate("text", label = foo_label, x = 1:5, y = 0, col="red") +
  theme_void() + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1,0,1,0, unit = "lines")) 

p_1/p_text + plot_layout(heights = c(1,0)) #this is a workaround to make the height of the text plot minimal!
```

[image]

You can then of course annotate with anything.

Answer (score 2):

For your stated goal, the ggtext library may be more appropriate, as it allows you to embed images directly into the x axis labels. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30652364/4975218) for another example.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

labels <- c(
  setosa = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Iris_setosa.JPG/180px-Iris_setosa.JPG'
    width='100' /><br>*I. setosa*",
  virginica = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Iris_virginica_-_NRCS.jpg/320px-Iris_virginica_-_NRCS.jpg'
    width='100' /><br>*I. virginica*",
  versicolor = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/20140427Iris_versicolor1.jpg/320px-20140427Iris_versicolor1.jpg'
    width='100' /><br>*I. versicolor*"
)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(
    name = NULL,
    labels = labels
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_markdown(color = "black", size = 11)
  )
```

[image]